# create data to three tables at once with Sequelizer

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I want to get data from form and based on that, add data to three tables in mySQL, I use Sequelize to do so, However I don't how to do so, my current idea gives error:

> Unhandled rejection Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers
>   after they are sent to the client

My code is like this:

```
app.post("/device/add", (req, res) => {
    db.Devices.create({
      device_id: req.body.device_id,
      server: req.body.server,
      type: req.body.type
    })
      .then(result => {
        res.json(result);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
      });

    db.Modules.create({
      device_id: req.body.device_id,
      device_options: req.body.device_options,,
      sleep_options: req.body.sleep_options
    })
      .then(result => {
        res.json(result);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
      });

    db.Tests.create({
      device_id: req.body.device_id,
      gsm_tests: req.body.gsm_tests,
      led_tests: req.body.led_tests,
    })
      .then(result => {
        res.json(result);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
      });
  });
```

can I somehow create it in one response? Or how to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to send again a response after you have sent one.

For more clarification, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

You can use Promise.all() to accumulate the results and then send it in one res.json() call.

```
const createDevice = db.Devices.create({
      device_id: req.body.device_id,
      server: req.body.server,
      type: req.body.type
    })

const createModules = db.Modules.create({
      device_id: req.body.device_id,
      device_options: req.body.device_options,
      sleep_options: req.body.sleep_options
    })
const createTests = db.Tests.create({
      device_id: req.body.device_id,
      gsm_tests: req.body.gsm_tests,
      led_tests: req.body.led_tests,
    })

Promise
    .all([createDevice , createModules , createTests ])
    .then(result=> {
        res.json({
                 devices: result[0],
                 modules: result[1],
                 test   : result[2]
              });

})
    .catch(err => {
       throw(err);
    });
```